# NSTextField value during edit is the field editors value. But I need the field's original value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

When I send `stringValue` to a `NSTextField` when it's field editor is active, it returns the current value from the field editor. But I need the original value from the `NSTextField` before it started editing! How can I get it? (tried to get the `stringValue` from the `NSTextFieldCell`, but I get the field editors value too) 
Any suggestions how I can get the original value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't ask the text field for its value, you should obtain the value from the model object that the text field represents.

Never store model data in a view. You should store it in a model object which is linked to the view through some sort of controller.

Comment: you're definitely right! The reason why I try to get that value is, that I wan't to make a TextField that only set's a new value if the old value is not the same. When I call setStringValue: and the original value of the field is the same as the new value, I don't want to overwrite the value because that changes the value in the field editor too. To test that in the model I need to do it every time before I set the value of the TextField and that's not comfortable at all.